# Why doesn't KStreamBinder have a lifecycle for DefaultBinding?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using KStream parameter in @StreamBuilder.

This will create a DefaultBinding through KStreamBinder.

My requirement is to use Binding visualization and control.

However

```java
return new DefaultBinding <> (name, null, outboundBindTarget, null);
```

You can't control the state via springboot /actuator/bindings because the lifecycle is null.

`(POST /actuator/bindings/{bindings-name} {"state":"PAUSED"})`

How can I control the state of a Binding?

The version I am using is below.

- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:3.0.1.RELEASE
- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core:3.0.1.RELEASE
- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.0.1.RELEASE
- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.3.1

please answer about my question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding visualization controls are not fully available in Kafka Streams binder in Spring Cloud Stream. If you can describe your use case as a new [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues), we can discuss this further there. Thank you.